# How to access mySQL database remotely from heroku node app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, localhost

I have a WordPress website on site-ground hosting. However, I've created a node/express server on Heroku that must have an access to the MySQL database on that WordPress website. Now we need MySQL credentials (HostName, UserName, Password, and databaseName) to run the queries. Normally to access the MySQL database from within the website, we use 'localhost' as the HostName. But I am not sure what HostName to use when accessing the database remotely (In my case from Heroku)

Comment: You need to talk to site-ground support and ask if this is even possible. Normally with such providers databases are not accessible outside their network.

Comment: chances are very low that you can access your database outside of the host's network  if you have a standard hosting. This kind of feature usually require a specific cloud database and is more expensive to rent.